# Adding a column with empty/null values to an anonymous list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, anonymous-types

Is it possible to add a column with empty (strings) or null values to an anonymous list? Here's what I've got:

```
var displayData = data.Select(res => new { res.Item1, res.Item2, res.Item3, ... }).ToList();
```

I want to add the column at the very end of this list.

Comment: Well... try giving it a name, for example `res => new { res.Item1, res.Item2, res.Item3, extraProperty = "" }`

Comment: Thanks--I didn't realize this would work. I'm still new to anonymous types and LINQ. Feel free to add it as an answer and I'll mark it ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the extra property a name, like so:

`res => new { res.Item1, res.Item2, res.Item3, extraProperty = "" }`